# Добавить метод который возвращает true если продукт свежий на сейчас или false в ином случае

Tags: java, классы, методы

Есть 4 фрукта с параметрами (тип, цвет, вес, цена за кг, дата изготовления и срок годности). Нужно добавить метод, который возвращает true если продукт свежий на сейчас или false в ином случае. Не могу понять, нужно ли переводить строку в число, как их связать? P.S. я только учусь, помогите кто чем может. Заранее спасибо.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    testFruits();
}

private static void testFruits() {
    Fruit[] fruits = new Fruit[4];

    Fruit lemon = new Fruit();

    lemon.setType(Fruit.TYPE_LEMON);
    lemon.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    lemon.setPricePerKg(36.99);
    lemon.setWeight(0.096);
    lemon.setDateOfManufacture("14.03.2018");
    lemon.setShelfLife(10);

    fruits[0] = lemon;

    Fruit banana = new Fruit();
    banana.setType(Fruit.TYPE_BANANA);
    banana.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    banana.setPricePerKg(37.99);
    banana.setWeight(0.206);
    banana.setDateOfManufacture("14.03.2018");
    banana.setShelfLife(8);

    fruits[1] = banana;

    Fruit redApple = new Fruit();
    redApple.setType(Fruit.TYPE_APPLE);
    redApple.setColor(Color.RED);
    redApple.setPricePerKg(28.99);
    redApple.setWeight(0.206);
    redApple.setDateOfManufacture("14.03.2018");
    redApple.setShelfLife(12);

    fruits[2] = redApple;

    Fruit greenApple = new Fruit();
    greenApple.setType(Fruit.TYPE_APPLE);
    greenApple.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    greenApple.setPricePerKg(20.99);
    greenApple.setWeight(0.184);
    greenApple.setDateOfManufacture("14.03.2018");
    greenApple.setShelfLife(11);

    fruits[3] = greenApple;


    double sum = getSum(fruits);
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);

}

private static double getSum(Fruit[] fruits) {
    double result = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
        result += fruits[i].getPrice();
        System.out.println("Fruit[" + i + "], price: " + fruits[i].getPrice());
    }

    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: `if (dateOfManufacture.AddMonths(shelfLife) > DateTime.Now) { /* fresh */ }`

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся, решил так:

```
private static boolean isFruitFresh(String dateOfManufacture, int shelfLife) throws Exception {
    Date today = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date dateFruit = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateOfManufacture);
    Calendar calendarToday = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarToday.setTime(today);
    Calendar calendarFruit = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarFruit.setTime(dateFruit);
    calendarFruit.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, shelfLife);
    if (calendarFruit.before(calendarToday)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

public static void printFreshness(Fruit[] fruits) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
            if (isFruitFresh(fruits[i].dateOfManufacture, fruits[i].shelfLife)) {
                System.out.println("Fruit[" + (i + 1) + "] is fresh");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Fruit[" + (i + 1) + "] is not fresh");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Метод должен сравнить кол-во дней между двумя датами - текущей и датой выпуска и если она больше срока годности - то выдать что-то.
Как пример:

```
    String date1 = "01.03.2016";
    String date2 = "01.02.2016";

      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

      Date dateOne = null;
      Date dateTwo = null;

      try {
          dateOne = format.parse(date1);
          dateTwo = format.parse(date2);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      // Количество дней между датами в миллисекундах
      long difference = dateOne.getTime() - dateTwo.getTime();
      // Перевод количества дней между датами из миллисекунд в дни
      int days =  (int)(difference / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // миллисекунды / (24ч * 60мин * 60сек * 1000мс)
      // Вывод разницы между датами в днях на экран
      System.out.println(days + " дн.");
```